# Getting UIImage from path only works while stepping through in debugger

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, debugging, uiimage

In my application I am saving an image to the devices "Documents" file and then later, retrieving it to use as a button background. I am testing this on 2 different devices, an iPhone 5 on iOS 8 and an iPhone 4 on iOS 7. The iPhone 5 works fine but I am having a very strange issue with the iPhone 4.

Setting the UIImage "imageToUse" with the following code only work when stepping through it in debug. If I place breakpoints before and after this block of code, the image will result to nil. If I step through it instead, the image sets properly.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    pathToSave = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    path = [pathToSave stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserIcons/%@", customIcon[i]]]; //customIcon[i] contains "userIcon0.jpg"
    imageToUse = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    // path contains "/var/mobile/Applications/7E6B8FFA-B56A-48EF-A788-CDB3842F8BB7/Documents/UserIcon‌​s/userIcon0.jpg"
```

This is a really strange problem that I have never run into before. Any ideas what might be the cause? Thanks all.

UPDATE: Here is my save method and folder check/creation as requested by matt.

```
    __block bool exit = NO;
    __block int count = 0;
    while (!exit) {

        // updated with matt's advice
        NSString *docs = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        Path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/UserSlides/userSlide%i.jpg", docs, count];

        // check to see if file already exists at the path
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:Path];
        // if the path is available, write to disk and then exit
        if (!fileExists) {
            [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(globe.customSlideImage, 1.0) writeToFile:Path atomically:NO];
            BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:Path];
            if (fileExists) {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save Complete"
                                                                message:nil
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                exit = YES;
            }
        }
        else { // otherwise increment the path file name and retry
            count++;
        }
    }

//////////////

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     dataPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/UserIcons"];
     if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: Is any of this code (saving the image or retrieving it) being executed in a background thread?

Comment: No it is not, I had some multi-threading going on but I cut it all to eliminate any issues with it.

Comment: Are you sure you eliminated it? :) Sorry to press, but it really sounds like that could be the source of the difficulty.

Comment: Could you show more code? How is the image saved? Where is this code running?

Comment: I just checked the model number and it is a 4 and it is running 7.1.2. I only had a few areas where I was multi-threading so it was easy to take out, but I will double check. Although I do agree with you that it acts like a multi-threading problem. The faster iPhone 5 does not have an issue.

Comment: Does the image come in multiple versions, e.g. `@2x`? There are bugs connected with this.

Comment: Well so much for my claim about the iPhone 4. :(

Comment: Negative, the image is created with the device camera and given a custom name in code, like "userImage0.jpg".

Comment: Ooooh, could the number be problematic? Try it without the `0`. Also please do some logging to show what `path` is; it must include the `.jpg` suffix.

Comment: I'm going to give an answer because it is very unlikely that the same value would work for both calls. This may not be the source of the problem but it could lead you to something.

Comment: Okay, so one problem is you are getting the directory all wrong. This is never going to work.

Comment: I'm going to leave you now to work on making your code for working with files coherent. Please see my book for more info on how to structure code for working with files and directories, starting here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_the_sandbox I have a feeling that it will be worthwhile for you to get this worked out before proceeding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have these two lines: in effect:

```
imageToUse = [UIImage imageNamed:path]; 
imageToUse = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Now, the problem here is that I would not expect *both* of those to work, *ever*. This is because they expect very different things.

- `imageNamed:` wants a simple *name*, such as `"myFile.jpg"`. It looks for the file *in your app bundle*, and nowhere else.
- `imageWithContentsOfFile:` wants a true pathname.

  - If the file is in your app bundle, this path can only be derived by starting with a call to `NSBundle.mainBundle()` and `pathForResource:ofType:` (or similar).
  - If the file is elsewhere, you need to use NSFileManager to get the containing folder and drill down from there.

Now, you say in your question that you are trying to get the file from the Documents folder. Well, `imageNamed:` can *never* get a file from there. My guess is that maybe a bug would allow you to get the file this way, but this is not something you should rely on. So your first step should be to eliminate that call entirely and concentrate on `imageWithContentsOfFile:`, which does what you want.

EDIT:

```
Path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/UserSlides/userSlide%i.jpg", count]];
```

Whoa. This is *not* the way to get your Documents directory. So, step one is to work correctly with these directories. To get the documents directory:

```
NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager new];
NSError* err = nil;
NSURL* docsurl =
    [fm URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
               inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil
                 create:YES error:&err];
```

Or, if you want a path string:

```
NSString* docs = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

Also I don't see your code doing anything about making sure that the intermediate *UserSlides* directory exists.

Comment: Here is the value of "path".                                                                                   /var/mobile/Applications/7E6B8FFA-B56A-48EF-A788-CDB3842F8BB7/Documents/UserIcons/userIcon0.jpg

Comment: OK but what happens if you do what I just said: delete the call to `imageNamed:` entirely?

Comment: And please do what I asked you to do: show more code. For example, how do I know that `pathToSave` is valid? How do I know how the file is being saved? If you want help you _must_ be more forthcoming with info!

Comment: Using only "imageWithContentsOfFile" maintains the same issue but extends it to the iPhone 5 as well. Give me a minute and I will post up more code in the initial question.

Comment: "Using only "imageWithContentsOfFile" maintains the same issue but extends it to the iPhone 5 as well." Good! Now we are working on just one problem. This is exactly the direction we want to go.

Comment: Ultimately the issue stemmed from from 3 things, 2 of which were pointed out in matt's answer. I needed to rework the way I was accessing my directories, I removed "[UIImage imageNamed:path]" because it worked but not reliably (likely a bug) and I also had a weak reference to my "imageToUse" property which I changed to strong. Now it all seems to be working well. Thanks matt.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think of the `weak` reference; this is in fact sort of like my original threading guess, so I was darned close. However, it was right to pare things down the way we did, so I'm glad it worked out.